# Get the return type of the function inside the function

Tags: typescript

In a generic function like this:

```
interface Foo<S,T> {
  state: S;
  type: T;
  valid: boolean;
}

function foo<S,A>(
  state: S,
  provider: TypeProvider<S, A>
): Foo<S,A> {
  const ret: Foo<S,A> = {
    state: provider.getState(state),
    type: provider.type()
  }
  ret.valid = false;
  return ret;
}
```

In the line:

```
const ret: Foo<S,A> = {
```

I will like to use a reference to the "current declare return type of the function" is any like this exist on Typescript >3.1.

I'm aware of `ReturnType<typeof foo>` but just want to know on other solutions.

Comment: Not possible. It would be tempting to write `ReturnType<typeof this>`, but itʼs not going to work.

Comment: I'm not clear where you want this, can you give an example?